# how to send email to a list member c#

Tags: c#

```
//server code
public void multie_send(MailMessage contact,string subject, string message)
{
    try
    {
        var userClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
        {
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(USER_ADRESS, USER_PASSWORD)
        };

        userClient.Send(USER_ADRESS, contact.ToString(), subject, message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

```
//client code
    MailMessage a = new MailMessage();
    a.To.Add("email1@gmail.com");
    a.To.Add("email2@yahoo.com");

    h1.multie_send(a, "hello world", "hello world");
```

and when i run this script,i get an error that say:"Additional information: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."

Comment: here are you getting the error?

Comment: Which line throws that exception and what are the runtime values used?

Comment: userClient.Send(USER_ADRESS, contact.ToString(), subject, message);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `contact.To.ToString()` in your method `multie_send`, instead of `contact.ToString()`.

Demo code (using a different and **better** variable name):

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add("email1@gmail.com");
message.To.Add("email2@yahoo.com");

Console.WriteLine(message.To.ToString());
```

Output:

> **email1@gmail.com, email2@yahoo.com**

I would very much recommend to use *better variable names*. If you would have used a parameter **`MailMessage message`** in the `multie_send` method (instead of naming it `contact`), then this problem might never have happened. The confusing name `contact` is possibly the reason behind your error.

Comment: if i use this code block, my error will be fixed?

Comment: The first line tells you what to do. The rest is a demo + a recommendation.

Comment: I used your solution,that's worked,thanks!❤

Comment: Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)